# Arduino doesn't turn off vibration after inputting 0

Tags: arduino

I have arduino UNO with bluetooth module and vibration motor attached. I can turn on the vibrator but cant seem to turn it off. Here's the code

```
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>//import the serial library

int vib=8;
SoftwareSerial Genotronex(10,11);//RX,TX
int BluetoothData;//the data given

void setup() {
Genotronex.begin(9600);
Genotronex.println("Bluetooth on please press 1 to vibrate");
pinMode(vib,OUTPUT);
// put your setup code here, to run once:
}

void loop() {
if (Genotronex.available()){
BluetoothData=Genotronex.read();{
if(BluetoothData='1'){
  digitalWrite(vib,'1');
  Genotronex.println("Vibrator on");
  delay(500);

  }
  else if (BluetoothData='0'){
  digitalWrite(vib,'0');
  Genotronex.println("Vibrator off");
  delay(500);

  }   
  }
  }
delay(100);
// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

In the bluetooth terminal, it stated 
<1> Vibrator on
when i input '1'
but also stated 
<0) Vibrator on
when i input '0' when it should've been Vibrator off.

Appreciate all the help

Comment: `'0'` and `'1'` are not the same as `0` and `1`. The first set is a string (or char) and the second set is an integer. Your `BluetoothData` variable is an integer so you'll need to compare it against an integer value. The same goes for your `digitalWrite` functions, you'll want to change those to integers or use `HIGH` and `LOW`

Comment: @TyloBedo: `'1'` is not a string. It's a character (`char` type). And as this is the `C++`, the character is numeric data type. So it's not a problem to compare char with the int (unless there are no data to read). However good point about `digitalWrite(vib, '0')`. This will be another issue. Not just using assign operator instead of compare one

Comment: Solved! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if(BluetoothData='1'){
                ^
```

Single `=` is assignment. Use `==` for comparisons.

Also, `BluetoothData` should probably be defined as a local variable in `loop()`. It'll work either way, but will compile to slightly more efficient (and more readable!) code.

Comment: `BluetoothData` is also defined as an int and it's trying to be compared against a string.

Comment: Expression `digitalWrite(vib,'0');` will result into logic 1 too. So fixing "always true" statement condition is not enough